# “From one gift come many”: Why not “comes”?

Tags: subject-verb-agreement, inversion

I want to ask about adding "s" to verbs. Sometimes I don't get an idea how to add this letter.

Example, are these sentences correct?

> Tom buys a car.
>   Tom buys cars.
>   Tom and Ruth buy a car.
>   Tom and Ruth buy cars.

I think these above sentences are correct.

But today I saw on Apple site this:

> From one gift come many.

I don't get why *come* is without "s"?
Because *gift* is singular. I know that Apple knows English better than I, but I don't get an idea why to use just *come* instead of *comes*?

Comment: The OP's example involves inversion, where the subject swapped locations with a clausal dependent: the subject is "many", and the dependent is "From one gift". A non-inverted version, where the subject comes first, could be: *"Many come from one gift"*, though that version seems to sound unidiomatic.

Comment: If I could I would vote to close because the question has nothing to do with English specifically.

Answer (score 19):

What you have here is an [ellipsis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis_%28linguistics%29). The full sentence is:

> From one gift come many [gifts].

*Gifts* is plural, and so is the verb. It's not the one gift that comes; it's many gifts that come from it.

Conversely, if it were "from one gift come**s** another [gift]", or "from one gift come**s** one more [gift]", or something like that, you'd use the singular.

Two general hints to help you recognize such things in the future:

1. *many* is a sure sign that you're looking at, or should be looking for, something plural
2. *from* is a sure sign that you're not looking at the nominative case, and so you're likely not looking at the subject of a clause (it's "he does", not "from him does", nor "from him do")

Comment: Standard word order (SVA) would be 'Many gifts come from one gift'. Google Ngram Viewer has no occurrences of 'one gift comes' or 'one gift come', but 'one _NOUN comes' and 'one _NOUN_ come' are both represented, with the first more common (not surprisingly).

Comment: English does not have any cases except Nominative and Possessive (other than in pronouns).

Comment: @Anixx English has cases alright. What you mean is that it does not have specific *forms* for these cases, so e.g. the nominative of *Tom* and the accusative of *Tom* are both *Tom*. But that doesn't mean that the accusative does not exist. The accusative of *Tom* is still the accusative. It is not the nominative.

Comment: @Anixx and RegDwight: In Huddleston and Pullum's 2005 textbook, *A Student's Introduction To English Grammar"*, page 107: *"In Present-day English the contrast between nominative and accusative forms is found only with personal pronouns and with interrogative and relative **who** (…). Other nouns appear in the same form in all the above constructions: …"*

Comment: (cont.) *"cf.* The [minister] wrote the editorial. Kim met the [minister] in Paris, *and so on. We use the term **plain form** here: to say that* minister *was nominative in the first and accusative in the second would be to make the mistake of confusing INFLECTIONAL CASE with GRAMMATICAL FUNCTION."*

Answer (score 8):

The rule involved is **subject verb agreement**.  A plural subject requires a plural verb.

The sentence in question makes identifying the subject a little tricky.  "Gift" may appear to be the subject but, in fact, it is the object of the preposition "from".

The subject is "many" which is plural, requiring the plural verb "come".

In general, nouns become plural by adding an "s" or "es" while verbs become singular by adding an "s".  I'm sure you can find exceptions, but that rule of thumb works for the majority of English words.